# Tensor Mapping Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning a little about reference frame associations and tensor mappings. I need to prove that $[T]_b=[C][T]_a[C]^T$ where T is a second order orthogonal tensor and C is a matrix. I am assuming its a relatively easy proof but I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly where to start. Any tips are greatly appreciated.